# Can I alter or analyse Exchange 2007 Content Filter Agent's scoring system?

Tags: exchange-2007, spam

I have a reasonably vanilla Exchange 2007 SP2 setup (Server Std. 2008) with a fairly liberal spam policy. I allow anything through with an SCL of 7 or lower and quarantine everything else. This lets some spam spam through but almost guarantees no false positives. (almost).

We have customers that manage their own lists that include our staff as recipients. It appears that a single delivery, addressed To: list@theircompany.com, but enveloped to three recipients at ourcompany.com got an SCL of 8, even though it picked up an active SPF pass on the way. It was particularly infuriating as it was quite an important message, timing-wise and previous messages to the same list  had been passed with no trouble. The agent log only shows the following:

```
[snip sender]  Content Filter Agent,OnEndOfData,QuarantineMessage,550 5.2.1 Content Filter agent quarantined this message,SclAtOrAboveQuarantineThreshold,8,DV:3.3.9515.631;SV:3.3.9007.60;SID:SenderIDStatus Pass
```

Now, I can whitelist some more domains and senders, but I hate having to pile up these explicit lists and I hate being beholden to black box systems that appear to arbitrarily break their own rules on a whim.

Could anyone tell me how I can see why it got an SCL of 8 (perhaps similar to what SpamAssassin would show), and whether it's possible to modify the weighting at all?

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The spam confidence level rating (SCL) may be [set by any installed content filter extension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998863.aspx), but the feature you probably mean is the Exchange Intelligent Message Filter is a black box - it changes with the definition updates issued by Microsoft every month. You might define [additional "blacklisted" or "whitelisted" keyword lists and recipients](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb124490.aspx), but aside from that, it is not configurable in the sense as SpamAssassin is. This is the reason why many Exchange administrators do use different message filtering techniques instead.

Comment: Figures. We use Forefront, too and the IMF does a reasonable job, it just has these occasional fits...

Comment: The TMG does its own content filtering on email traffic if configured accordingly: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee338733.aspx It does not have significantly more configuration options, though. BTW: in my experience, the IMF performs rather badly compared to even an out-of-the-box Amavis/Spamassassin installation. For Windows the Perl-based ASSP could be used as well, although I found it rather tiresome to configure and the daemon did hang occasionally in test installations.